# Не отображается тулбар в фрагменте

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Вот код который использую в фрагменте .

```
 public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search);

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(searchQueryListener);
    }
```

Вот код активити

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Вы привели код относящийся к меню. Как он относится к вашей проблеме отсутствия тулбара? Покажите разметку и стили

Comment: Сам тулбар есть, но на нем не компонентов. Извините за некоректно поставленьй вопрос.

Comment: Попробуйте super.onCreateOptionsMenu вызвать в конце метода а не в начале

Comment: В фрагменте ? я тут вьзвал  super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

Comment: Я исправил коммент

Comment: Не помогло, компонента нет.

Comment: Все пункты отсюда выполнены? http://stackoverflow.com/a/18319050/3212712 не вызываете ли вы super дважды? А если clear убрать? Добавьте в вопрос что вы пытались сделать для решения проблемы

Comment: Делал все по етому образцу. Один super в onCreateView другой в onCreateOptionMenu

Comment: Проверьте ещё раз. В примере супер в onCreate, не в onCreateView. Дважды всё проверьте

Comment: Переместил в onCreate. Результат не поменялся.

Comment: Больше в приведенном коде ошибок нет.проблема в непоепзанном коде

Comment: Я даже не знаю. Скажите какую часть вам отправить. Я не могу найти ошибку, пол дня ищу уже.

Comment: Попробуйте создать чистый проект и в нем реализовать. Выложите его на гитхаб. Посмоьрю

Comment: Давайте я етот вьложу. Тут все ровно проблема в одном фрагменте.

Comment: Ладно, выкладывайте этот. А искать меня не надо. Я только тут тусуюсь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас всё плохо в коде. Приведите его в порядок. Следите за подсказками студии. Она выделяет цветом спорные места, в т.ч. неиспользуемые переменные. У вас в разметке есть Тулбар который вы не назначили ActionBar-ом. Т.е. надо прописать во фрагменте

```
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Плюс вы неправильный выбрали подход. ActionBar должен быть в актвити, а фрагмент должен лишь его менять. Не нужен вам (на 99% уверен) тулбар во фрагменте. Он в актвити должен быть. Т.е. в её разметке.

P.S. плюс у вас что-то с FAB - с ним приложение сразу падает

Comment: Спасибо Юрий, ето помогло, только у меня теперь всего по два. два одинаковьх поиска и две одинаковье кнопки.

Comment: Видимо у вас дважды меню добавляется. В актвити и во фрагменте. Кстати. `ЭТО` пишется через `Э` - очень глаз режет